# SVG2PNG font not recognized on Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, discord.js

Im trying to build a discord bot that responds with an image. But the TextFont not correct, charakters displayed as "[]"

[image: Font not correct, charakters displayed as "[]"]
My Code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { svg2png } = require('svg-png-converter');
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
let declareCount = 0;

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('test')
        .setDescription('dei!'),


    async execute(interaction) {
        let svg = 
        `
        <svg height="30" width="200">
        <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
      </svg>
        `

          declareCount+=1;
          const outputBuffer = await svg2png({
              input: svg,
              encoding: 'buffer',
              format: 'png',
              quality: 1
          })
          await interaction.reply({
            ephemeral: false,
            content: `Test #${declareCount}`,
            files: [new MessageAttachment(outputBuffer, '${name}.png')]
        });
      },
    };
```

Everything works on my local windows system. Is there any way, to do it with linux?
Thanks in regards

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks good to me. Maybe you check if your code is generating valid svg.

use `svgvalidate` for the same.

```
const { svgvalidate } = require('svgvalidate');
```

And in your code just before `const outputBuffer` use the following code:

```
if (!svgvalidate(svg)) {
  throw new Error('Invalid SVG');
}
```

I don't know if you have already tried this but, try installing required node modules in linux machine.

Comment: No error thrown. SVG is valid.

Comment: maybe if you try to fresh install node modules might help. Delete the node modules folder and run `npm install`

Comment: I've already done that. I also tried adding it with <style>, but nothing worked :/

Comment: I now get: "
0|index  | Fontconfig error:
0|index  | Cannot load default config file
"

Running on Linux VPS

Comment: You may try to set the `$FONTCONFIG_PATH` properly, in `/etc/profile` or if you are just using terminal, maybe try:

`export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts`
in your .bashrc or .zshrc file